# php while loop ending unexpectedly

Tags: php, html, while-loop

So, I'm writing a custom website for a photographer. I am trying to make it mobile first, and make sure everything can work without javascript. I decided to use a php while loop to create a really long string, for a script tag that I am injecting next to some html. I do not want to put this into css because I am sure I will have to change it slightly in the future. Anyway, the loop is very simple, but it is ending early. really early, and I do not know why. I am wondering if it is simply timing out, but I cannot be sure. Any help on fixing this is appreciated:

```
    <?php
    echo "<style>";
    $imgClass = "hzPic";
    $i0 = 20;
    $theString = "";
    while($i0 < 200){
        $theString = $theString."@media screen and (min-height:".($i0*10)."px){ .".$imgClass."s{ height: ".($i0 - 13)."em; } }\n";
        ++$i0;
    }
    echo $theString;
    echo "</style>";
    ?>
```

EDIT

```
@media screen and (min-height:200px){ .hzPics{ height: 7em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:210px){ .hzPics{ height: 8em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:220px){ .hzPics{ height: 9em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:230px){ .hzPics{ height: 10em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:240px){ .hzPics{ height: 11em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:250px){ .hzPics{ height: 12em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:260px){ .hzPics{ height: 13em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:270px){ .hzPics{ height: 14em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:280px){ .hzPics{ height: 15em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:290px){ .hzPics{ height: 16em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:300px){ .hzPics{ height: 17em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:310px){ .hzPics{ height: 18em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:320px){ .hzPics{ height: 19em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:330px){ .hzPics{ height: 20em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:340px){ .hzPics{ height: 21em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:350px){ .hzPics{ height: 22em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:360px){ .hzPics{ height: 23em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:370px){ .hzPics{ height: 24em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:380px){ .hzPics{ height: 25em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:390px){ .hzPics{ height: 26em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:400px){ .hzPics{ height: 27em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:410px){ .hzPics{ height: 28em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:420px){ .hzPics{ height: 29em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:430px){ .hzPics{ height: 30em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:440px){ .hzPics{ height: 31em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:450px){ .hzPics{ height: 32em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:460px){ .hzPics{ height: 33em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:470px){ .hzPics{ height: 34em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:480px){ .hzPics{ height: 35em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:490px){ .hzPics{ height: 36em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:500px){ .hzPics{ height: 37em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:510px){ .hzPics{ height: 38em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:520px){ .hzPics{ height: 39em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:530px){ .hzPics{ height: 40em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:540px){ .hzPics{ height: 41em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:550px){ .hzPics{ height: 42em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:560px){ .hzPics{ height: 43em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:570px){ .hzPics{ height: 44em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:580px){ .hzPics{ height: 45em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:590px){ .hzPics{ height: 46em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:600px){ .hzPics{ height: 47em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:610px){ .hzPics{ height: 48em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:620px){ .hzPics{ height: 49em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:630px){ .hzPics{ height: 50em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:640px){ .hzPics{ height: 51em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:650px){ .hzPics{ height: 52em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:660px){ .hzPics{ height: 53em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:670px){ .hzPics{ height: 54em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:680px){ .hzPics{ height: 55em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:690px){ .hzPics{ height: 56em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:700px){ .hzPics{ height: 57em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:710px){ .hzPics{ height: 58em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:720px){ .hzPics{ height: 59em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:730px){ .hzPics{ height: 60em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:740px){ .hzPics{ height: 61em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:750px){ .hzPics{ height: 62em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:760px){ .hzPics{ height: 63em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:770px){ .hzPics{ height: 64em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:780px){ .hzPics{ height: 65em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:790px){ .hzPics{ height: 66em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:800px){ .hzPics{ height: 67em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:810px){ .hzPics{ height: 68em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:820px){ .hzPics{ height: 69em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:830px){ .hzPics{ height: 70em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:840px){ .hzPics{ height: 71em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:850px){ .hzPics{ height: 72em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:860px){ .hzPics{ height: 73em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:870px){ .hzPics{ height: 74em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:880px){ .hzPics{ height: 75em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:890px){ .hzPics{ height: 76em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:900px){ .hzPics{ height: 77em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:910px){ .hzPics{ height: 78em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:920px){ .hzPics{ height: 79em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:930px){ .hzPics{ height: 80em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:940px){ .hzPics{ height: 81em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:950px){ .hzPics{ height: 82em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:960px){ .hzPics{ height: 83em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:970px){ .hzPics{ height: 84em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:980px){ .hzPics{ height: 85em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:990px){ .hzPics{ height: 86em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1000px){ .hzPics{ height: 87em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1010px){ .hzPics{ height: 88em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1020px){ .hzPics{ height: 89em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1030px){ .hzPics{ height: 90em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1040px){ .hzPics{ height: 91em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1050px){ .hzPics{ height: 92em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1060px){ .hzPics{ height: 93em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1070px){ .hzPics{ height: 94em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1080px){ .hzPics{ height: 95em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1090px){ .hzPics{ height: 96em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1100px){ .hzPics{ height: 97em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1110px){ .hzPics{ height: 98em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1120px){ .hzPics{ height: 99em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1130px){ .hzPics{ height: 100em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1140px){ .hzPics{ height: 101em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1150px){ .hzPics{ height: 102em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1160px){ .hzPics{ height: 103em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1170px){ .hzPics{ height: 104em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1180px){ .hzPics{ height: 105em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1190px){ .hzPics{ height: 106em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1200px){ .hzPics{ height: 107em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1210px){ .hzPics{ height: 108em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1220px){ .hzPics{ height: 109em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1230px){ .hzPics{ height: 110em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1240px){ .hzPics{ height: 111em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1250px){ .hzPics{ height: 112em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1260px){ .hzPics{ height: 113em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1270px){ .hzPics{ height: 114em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1280px){ .hzPics{ height: 115em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1290px){ .hzPics{ height: 116em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1300px){ .hzPics{ height: 117em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1310px){ .hzPics{ height: 118em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1320px){ .hzPics{ height: 119em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1330px){ .hzPics{ height: 120em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1340px){ .hzPics{ height: 121em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1350px){ .hzPics{ height: 122em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1360px){ .hzPics{ height: 123em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1370px){ .hzPics{ height: 124em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1380px){ .hzPics{ height: 125em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1390px){ .hzPics{ height: 126em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1400px){ .hzPics{ height: 127em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1410px){ .hzPics{ height: 128em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1420px){ .hzPics{ height: 129em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1430px){ .hzPics{ height: 130em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1440px){ .hzPics{ height: 131em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1450px){ .hzPics{ height: 132em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1460px){ .hzPics{ height: 133em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1470px){ .hzPics{ height: 134em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1480px){ .hzPics{ height: 135em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1490px){ .hzPics{ height: 136em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1500px){ .hzPics{ height: 137em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1510px){ .hzPics{ height: 138em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1520px){ .hzPics{ height: 139em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1530px){ .hzPics{ height: 140em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1540px){ .hzPics{ height: 141em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1550px){ .hzPics{ height: 142em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1560px){ .hzPics{ height: 143em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1570px){ .hzPics{ height: 144em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1580px){ .hzPics{ height: 145em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1590px){ .hzPics{ height: 146em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1600px){ .hzPics{ height: 147em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1610px){ .hzPics{ height: 148em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1620px){ .hzPics{ height: 149em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1630px){ .hzPics{ height: 150em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1640px){ .hzPics{ height: 151em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1650px){ .hzPics{ height: 152em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1660px){ .hzPics{ height: 153em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1670px){ .hzPics{ height: 154em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1680px){ .hzPics{ height: 155em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1690px){ .hzPics{ height: 156em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1700px){ .hzPics{ height: 157em; } }
@media screen and (min-height:1710px){ .hzPics{ height: 158…
```

this is the actual output I am getting. As you can see it is stopping at about 171 for me. I cannot seem to figure out why.
And yes, I want it to concatenate.

Comment: Specify what you mean by *really early*!

Comment: can you post that half-way string also?

Comment: well, this actually works fine for me ... going all up to 199. And it's quite fast also, so it shouldn't timeout also ...

Comment: @Dagon it's concatenating not overwriting: `$theString = $theString."@media..."`

Comment: Any chance you're using Xdebug and wrapping this echo in an output buffer?

Comment: I have no idea what that means, so no.

Comment: the ellipsis is in the actual output?  you're using some tool that has truncated what you're actually producing.

Comment: would google chrome do something like this?

Comment: because that's the only thing that I am using... that and my text editor

Comment: I think it was caused by the variable being too big. I literally think the string was too large to be parsed and rewritten quick enough. it may have just been dropped. has anyone heard of this happening?

Comment: nevermind. It has to be timing out. I am able to control where the string is truncated by how many pieces characters are in the string.

Comment: it is clocking out at 10,001 characters. does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) - though there is probably something else at work, you're not doing anything particularly resource-hungry, there's no reason why it should do what you suggest.  Are you using a *free* host or something with some wacky settings...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use concatenation `.`  to join the string. I am not sure what mean early finishing. You can use `$i++` (adds after) instead of `++$i` (adds before).

```
 echo "<style>";
        $imgClass = "hzPic";
        $i = 20;
        $theString = "";
        while($i < 200){
            $theString .= '@media screen and (min-height:'.($i*10).'px){ .'.$imgClass.'s{ height: '.($i - 13).'em; } }';
            ++$i;
        }
        echo $theString;
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question :/ Also, the precedence of the suffix/postfix operators is only effective in a single expression - in this example it makes no difference.